# jquery loop through row and add background color

Tags: jquery

I'm looping through my grid and looking at the last column to see if there are any text. If there are, I want to add css background color. What I have right now seems to work a bit but not fully because it's adding a background color even if there is/isnt any text. Can any help me resolve this?

```
$('.SelectRow').each(function(){
            var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var lastRow = row.children('td:eq(7)').text();
            alert(lastRow);

            if(lastRow != " ") 
                row.css("background-color", "red");    
        });
```

Comment: You are checking that the text isn't equal to a space only. So if your string contains ANYTHING else, no space, a period, actual text it will evaluate to true. Is that the desired intention or is the check for a space a mistake and should be an empty string?

Comment: what's in the jQuery object with selector `.SelectRow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.SelectRow').each(function(){
            var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var lastRow = row.children('td:eq(7)').text();
            alert(lastRow);

            if($.trim(lastRow) != "") 
                row.css("background-color", "red");    
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using the `:empty` selector):

```
$('.SelectRow').each(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    if (!row.children('td:eq(7):empty').length) {   
        row.css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using lastRow.length

```
if(lastRow.length > 0)
    row.css("background-color", "red");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($.trim(lastRow) != "")
    row.css('background-color', 'red');
```